# For what Intel's AVX-512 has 32 (so many!) 512-bit register vectors, ZMM0 to ZMM31?

Tags: x86, avx512

Intel's AVX512 technology supports parallelization due to multiple subregisters, e.g. there are 8 64-bit FP-subregisters in each 512-bit vector register. And what, the multiple vector registers may operate in parallel as well? Does the following symbolic example of parallelization take place?

parbegin;

```
 ZMM0 (operation) ZMM1 -> ZMM2;  

 ZMM3 (operation) ZMM4 -> ZMM5;  
 ...  
 ZMM27 (operation) ZMM28 -> ZMM29;
```

parend;

Comment: What do you mean by "so many"? It's just 32 of them.

Comment: More registers = more room to hide latencies by keeping more operations in flight.

Answer (score 3):

### 1. "there are 8 64-bit FP-subregisters in each 512-bit vector register"

This is **not true** according to [1](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/26/40/319433-026.pdf) that

> AVX-512 instructions support 512-bit wide SIMD registers (ZMM0-ZMM31). The lower 256-bits of the ZMM registers are aliased to the respective 256-bit YMM registers and the lower 128-bit are aliased to the respective 128-bit 
>   XMM registers.
>
> AVX-512 instructions also support for 32 SIMD registers in 64-bit mode (XMM0-XMM31, YMM0-YMM31 and ZMM0-ZMM31). The number of available vector registers in 32-bit mode is still 8.

### 2. May "multiple vector registers operate in parallel"?

This is more complicated since AVX512 is an extension of SIMD **instructions** which not all meant to be supported by all processors implementing them.

I can only guess (I highly recommend that you rephrase your question or attach an example for detailed analysis) that what you meant is if multiple instructions can all issued in one cycle? The short answer, IMOP, is that it depends on the specific architectures.

A recommended reading is "Intel 64 and IA32 Architectures Optimization Reference Manual" [2](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/9e/bc/64-ia-32-architectures-optimization-manual.pdf) even though it does not yet include the only AVX512-ready microchip on market - Xeon Phi (code name Knights Landing). At least it shows that the "throughput" is related to execution ports and functional units of specific instructions, see Appendix C-3.

As for your mini-example, since it uses only register operands, most likely that these can all be issued in one cycle.